# Получить id потока в котором был создан экземпляр класса

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++17

Можно ли проверить находится ли объект `application` и `window` в одном потоке?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    window window("Test Window");
    vulkan_renderer renderer(window); // Класс окна теперь владеет данным объектом
    application app;
    return app.run(window);
}
```

Теперь я хочу в методе `run` проверить, находится ли переданный `window` в том же потоке что и `application`

```
int application::run(window& window)
{
    std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();

    MSG msg{};
    std::memset(&msg, 0, sizeof msg);
    window.show();
    while(window.is_open())
    {
        if(PeekMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
        // some other code goes here
    }

    return int(msg.wParam);
}
```

Получить `std::thread::id` текущего класса `application` довольно просто, но вот как получить `id` объекта `window` без дополнительного метода в классе `window` и вообще возможно ли это?

Comment: Как бы это сказать... Словом, поток - это понятие кода, а объект - скорее данных. Скажем, вы передаете в поток ссылку на объект - и все, вызов функции объекта, в которой вызывается `this_thread::get_id();`, даст просто поток, в котором этот вызов сделан. Можно говорить в лучшем случае об объектах в стеке функции потока, но не передаваемых в функцию как аргумент.

Comment: Т.е. даже если сделать метод который возвращал бы `id` в классе `window` вернет тот же `id` потока из которого был вызван данный метод?

Comment: Достаточно добавить в каждый класс по неизменяемому полю с идентификатором потока, в котором был вызван конструктор.